# Server Load for SAP Secure Network Connection Encryption

Tags: sap-basis

If you turn on encryption in SAP between the client and the server using the Secure Network Connection (SAP SNC), then is there a load placed on the server to do all the encryption work?  How big a load?  Is it equivalent to the difference between HTTP and HTTPS on a web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clarify what you want to do.

Do you just want to create secure RFC connections from the SAP GUI to the SAP system? Which 3rd party security product will you be using (e.g. Kerberos).

Will you be using Single Sign On? i.e. via an AD server. If so, where will the secure connection be - full end to end?

With encryption, the main load is during the initial handshaking between the client and the server. During this process, keys are calculated and exchanged.

See the [SNC User's Guide](https://websmp107.sap-ag.de/~sapdownload/011000358700001270931999E/SNCHBEN.PDF) for information.

I have not seen any references to the load on the system. I did ask SAP OSS years ago but did not get a satisfactory reply.

You cannot compare the load of SNC (using DIAG) to HTTPS because the protocols are very different - DIAG is a lot leaner.

I have investigated the use of [F5 servers](http://www.f5.com/). They can be used for software and hardware accelleration of HTTPS, but not for the DIAG protocol.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  You'll no doubt gather from the lack of detail in the question that we haven't clarified exactly what it is we want and are assessing options.